# handler change Select input object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I mapped option select data from the Api but i have problem to change value of select input i use this handler change but the input can't change value is always fix  what is the error in my code?
how can i change the input value
My error is like this is look please in the link video

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/796

All the code in the same component

initialValues

```
const initialStates = {
         rug: {nom: "", id: "" }
    }


    const [currentStates, setCurrentStates] = useState(initialStates);
```

handle change methode

```
    const handleChange = event =>{
        setCurrentStates({ ...rugList[event.target.value].drug.id });
    };
```

Select input

```
  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridDrug">
                                                        
<Form.Label> Select</Form.Label>
                                                       
 <Form.Control required as="select"
                                                          
  type="text"
                                                           
 id="rug.id"
                                                           
 name="rug.id"
                                                           
 value={currentStates.rug.id}
                                                           
 className={"bg-white text-dark"}
                                                           
 onChange={handleChange}
                                                      
  >
                                                         
   <option value="">Choice select</option>
                                                           
 {rugList.map((value) =>
                                                               
 <option value={value.id} key={value.id}>
                                                                  
  {value.nom}
                                                               
 </option>
                                                            
)}

                                                       
 </Form.Control>

                                                   
 </Form.Group>
```

Comment: where is `initialStates` initialized - is it outside this component?

Comment: No it is inside the component the error is in the handel change can’t work my error is like this issue look please in this link video https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/796

Comment: you are linking an issue from `react-select` repo but it doesn't seem that you are using this library

Comment: No I don’t use it , but show you the video it is like my error ;(

Comment: you are using react-bootstrap right?

Comment: Yes I use react-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rugList` is an array with objects with shape `{id , nom }`. your `handleChange` needs to find a an object at `rugList` with an `id` property that matches `event.target.value` to set `currentStates` correctly:

```
  const handleChange = event => {
      const rug = rugList.find(({ id }) => id === event.target.value);
      if(rug) setCurrentStates({ rug });
  };
```